# How to replace all of the X's with 0's using regexp

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to replace a string of n X's with a string of n 0's using postgres. This command only replaces the first X with an O. So 3XX turns into 30X.

```
regexp_replace("BLOCK_ADDRESS", 'X', '0')
```

I want it to be 300.

What do I change?

Comment: You mixed `O` and `0` in your title and your question.  Which one did you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

> The `flags` parameter is an optional text string containing zero or more single-letter flags that change the function's behavior. Flag `i` specifies case-insensitive matching, while flag `g` specifies replacement of each matching substring rather than only the first one.

So you want:

```
regexp_replace("BLOCK_ADDRESS", 'X', '0', 'g')
```